# SQL Server: copy all tables into new tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am having a problem.

I am trying to create an easy way to make a copy of `Table1` to `Table2`. Now I know the `Select Into`, but in this there is say table 1 through table 100 and I am trying to create a duplicate of all of them. SSIS or SQL is OK.

The reason for the copy is say I have 2 tables within a classes database.  Alegra 101 and 102, I am trying to create algebra 103   this will work for all of the tables, like Health 101 and 102, assume there are around 100 different classes with a 101 level and a 102 level that need a 103.

Comment: Something like http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/11/ssis-copy-all-tables.html scratch your itch?

Comment: The only issue with that is in the work environment that I have I can't use anything but SQL or SSIS. Also with that is trying to create a separate database this will all be contained within the same database just creating a table

Comment: That is *just* SSIS. It's an automated way of generating SSIS packages. The sample shows copying server0.catalogA.dbo.table1 to server1.catalogB.dbo.table1 but nothing prevents you from adapting it to a pure table copy.

Comment: Alarm bells! Why would you create Algebra101, Algebra102, Algebra103? Why not just add a single column to a single Algebra table

Comment: I'm with @ElectricLlama - the fundamental premise is flawed.

Comment: Based on comments below.. 'it's what I have to work with'. I suggest you make it clear to your superior that you have substantial **Technical Debt** in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of dynamic SQL, but you might get away with something like this.
Maybe you should give some more insight in to why you might want to "copy" tables - others may have more suitable solutions for you.

```
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @CMD = @CMD + 'SELECT * INTO [dbo].[Copy_' + TABLE_NAME + ']' + ' FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ';' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
--  Add your filtering criteria as a WHERE clause

PRINT @CMD  --  to check the code generated

-- EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @CMD ***UNCOMMENT WHEN READY***
```

In light of you adding the reason for your needs, I would seriously reconsider my model. Instead of having n tables, (1 per subject\class) - a more suitable model would be to keep all homogeneous data in the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE Class
(
    ClassID     INT,
    YearOfClass INT,
    ...
    ...
    ClassSubject    VARCHAR(50) -- This could be an FK to a ClassSubject Table
)
```

Where ClassSubject is populated with values 'Algebra 101', 'Algebra 102' etc...
This will save you from having to create tables every time a new subject is added - and having to adjust all your stroed procs accordingly. Amoung many other benefits, aggregations also become simpler.

Comment: I added the reason why in my question. Sorry.

Comment: In light of that, it may be a good idea to just add a column to your table, indicating which class the row is related to. Will update my answer...

Comment: The classes are their own tables, algebra 101 Is a separate table than 102

Comment: I understand that - and I think thats a mistake :)

Comment: Tis not optimal however it is what I have to work with. Unfortunately I cannot change this

Comment: Thats unfortunate. Does the dynamic SQL solution work for you then?